# Is it possible to embed a .xml file into a conda package?

Tags: python, package, conda

I am developing a conda package for Python.
Some behaviour of the code depends on information stored into a .xml file.

I do not want my package to depend on an external file that should be distributed along with the package, and that must be found by it.

Is there a way to embed this .xml file into the conda package when I build it?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, you can use [`build.sh` or `bld.bat` scripts](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/build-scripts.html) to add arbitrary files to the conda package.

Comment: Thanks! I went on the link you shared, but I still cannot figure out how to include additional files to the package. Looking at the example ( https://github.com/AnacondaRecipes/conda-feedstock/tree/master/recipe) does not help either. Could you share a working example?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't spend enough time to understand the use case. I posted a way that should solve your problem without treating conda packaging special. This approach installs and locates the data directly with setuptools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing a python package, a straightforward way to solve this problem is by using setuptools directly for shipping additional data:

A simple example project could look like this

```
example_project
├── Manifest.in
├── data
│   └── data.xml
├── setup.py
└── test_me
    └── __init__.py
```

The individual parts:

`data/data.xml` (the data you want to ship with your package):

```
<data>
    <message>Hello World!</message>
</data>
```

`test_me/__init__.py` (an example for reading out the data in your package):

```
from pkg_resources import Requirement, resource_filename
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_file = resource_filename(Requirement.parse("MyPythonPackageName"), "data/data.xml")

etree = ET.parse(xml_file)
message = etree.getroot()[0].text
```

`Manifest.in` (ensuring that when building distributions the data is included):

```
include data/data.xml
```

`setup.py` (a minimal setup script; note that we explicitly set `include_package_data`):

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='MyPythonPackageName',
    version='1.0.0',
    author='Me',
    author_email='author@me.com',
    description='additional resource example',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True
)
```

To test it, you would install it from the top level directory by `pip install .` and then print the message in the xml with `python -c "import test_me; print(test_me.message)"`

The conda package then is just installing the python package, there should be no extra steps needed.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, i think that will work for me thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how this line works: 
`resource_filename(Requirement.parse("TestMe"), "data/data.xml")`
Does it knows that 'TestMe' is indeed the directory test_me?

Comment: Ok, I understand my misunderstanding, `TestMe` is the name of the package.